# VS2019 add custom script to publishing process

Tags: automation, visual-studio-2019, publishing

How to perform own program before/after FolderPublish event in VS2019?
Not interesting at all how to add custom build script, it working and can be adding manually or by VS2019 project editor.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>echo $(PublishDir)</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My question exactly about processing project publishing event, I try to use

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <Target Name="ActionsBeforePublish" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <Exec Command="echo YES"  />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="ActionsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="echo $(PublishDir)"  />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

but its not working. I don't see "YES" in publishing output window.